# mysql timestamp error with time.Now() golang

Tags: go

How to save `time.Now()` in mysql table, column name as `created_at timestamp null`.

I am getting error :

```
Error:Error 1292: Incorrect datetime value: '2017-08-05 19:06:14.190 +0000' for column 'created_at' at row 1
```

### More Information as asked :- ( I am using `fragmenta` cms, so all reference code with their line number is given below )

Table schema :-

```
mysql> describe users;
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                   | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| created_at           | timestamp    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at           | timestamp    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status               | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| role                 | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| name                 | varchar(250) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email                | varchar(250) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| title                | varchar(250) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| summary              | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| text                 | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| image_id             | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| password_hash        | varchar(250) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| password_reset_token | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| password_reset_at    | timestamp    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Code that is running it to save :-

At line no. 62 here ( https://github.com/fragmenta/fragmenta-cms/blob/master/src/pages/actions/setup.go#L62 )

It calls code 

`user := users.New()`

in Line no. 51 at file here ( https://github.com/fragmenta/fragmenta-cms/blob/master/src/users/query.go#L51 )

`New()` function is setup.

Which is like :-

```
func New() *User {
    user := &User{}
    user.CreatedAt = time.Now()
    user.UpdatedAt = time.Now()
    user.TableName = TableName
    user.KeyName = KeyName
    user.Status = status.Draft
    return user
}
```

and their connecting / mysql opening pattern is located here ( https://github.com/fragmenta/query/blob/master/adapters/database_mysql.go#L23 ) .

Comment: Include `parseTime=True` in your MySQL connection string and try.

Comment: `charset=utf8&parseTime=true` is already there

Comment: Can you please share your DB's schema ?

Comment: Then it is MySQL DB Timezone setting issue not a Go issue. Can you please check your Db setting.

Comment: Just if it helps - I am using `fragmenta` CMS with `mysql`.

Comment: @JohnCargo Can you please share the code which builds the query ?

Comment: @ShmulikKlein , Updated my question with all relevant code and link to solve the error.

Comment: @ShmulikKlein does this help now ?

Comment: @Jeevatkm does this help now ?

Comment: I had a look on provide CMS codebase. I surely feel this is MySQL setting for `error code 1292`, refer to this [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/48745) and do your setting according to your MySQL version.  Quick way to check this fire `INSERT` query in your SQL editor, you will see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug in [`https://github.com/fragmenta/query`](https://github.com/fragmenta/query). The `TimeString` method in `query/adapters/database.go` is not valid for all DBMS adapters.

```
// TimeString - given a time, return the standard string representation
func (db *Adapter) TimeString(t time.Time) string {
    return t.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05.000 -0700")
}
```

It's not valid for a MySQL timestamp: [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual, 11.3.1 The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html). The MySQL `TimeString` method in `query/adapters/database_mysql.go` should be:

```
// TimeString - given a time, return the MySQL standard string representation
func (db *MysqlAdapter) TimeString(t time.Time) string {
    return t.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05.999999")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to insert it using a string [query.go:36](https://github.com/fragmenta/fragmenta-cms/blob/master/src/lib/resource/query.go#L36):

```
now := query.TimeString(time.Now().UTC())
```

that is generated by the package that you are using [database.go:59](https://github.com/fragmenta/query/blob/master/adapters/database.go#L59):

```
return t.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05.000 -0700")
```

MySQL expects it to be in the pattern of `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`, use the following snippet to apply the pattern to you current `Time.time` object:

```
now := time.Now().UTC().Format("2006-01-02 03:04:05")
```

Anyway, why not to use the SQL function `NOW()` when inserting the record ?

Comment: Even after changing it to `time.Now().UTC()` - it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Can you please turn the `Debug` flag on https://github.com/fragmenta/query/blob/master/query.go#L22 and tell what is the generated query ?

Comment: It's in debug mode by default and gives same error as i have mentioned in question `File:src/pages/actions/setup.go:65
Error:Error 1292: Incorrect datetime value: '2017-08-05 21:51:07.723 +0000' for column 'created_at' at row 1`

Comment: The boolean that I mentioned should print out the generated query for you

Comment: Nope! it has not any - it only gives error message with file name and line number.